# Как использовать технологию единого входа в вебе?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel, openid

Мне нужно узнать о технологии единого входа. Есть несколько продуктов и нужно реализовать эту технологию для того что бы пользователи могли использовать единый аккаунт для входа в любое из приложений. Я почти ничего не знаю по этой теме и мне нужна помощь, консультация.. Как использовать эту технологию, какие есть стандарты, подходят ли для этого OpenID или OAuth, есть ли уже готовые реализации на php или Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте о SSO.
Вам нужен сервис, который будет отвечать за авторизацию и предоставления некого токена. Так же придется доработать каждое приложение, которое сможет работать с этим сервисом.

Необязательно держать сервис SSO на php. Вот несколько готовых продуктов, которые реализуют SSO:

- https://github.com/ory/hydra
- https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas/about-cas

Возможно есть готовый сервис на php, но так глубоко не копал.

PS: у ory/hydra есть SDK на php.

Comment: С таким же успехом могу посоветовать Keycloak. Сам использую не безуспешно в, что называется, продакшине. Но нубу это вряд ли поможет быстро войти в курс дела. Точно не помню, но вроде на хабре попадалась самая доходчивая статья про oauth из всех какие мне попадались по этой теме.